# Permission Sets automatically updated by Spring22 migration: rights removed

Tags: permission-sets, migration, upgrade, spring22

One of our production org has been **automatically migrated to Spring22** by Salesforce last week-end

The following jobs has been run by SF platform during the update (audit trail extract)

[image]

**After this upgrade, all of the permission set has been automatically updated**:

- For some of them, **all fieldAccess has been removed** (Standard and Custom fields)
- For some of them, **only some fieldAccess has been removed** (again standard and/or custom fields)

All Permission Sets, even the ones not in our CI, even Salesforce Internal ones, has been automatically updated, it can not be from a manual operation

[image]

- Has anyone observed the same error on his/her production org after Spring22 update ?
- Is there some "one-click" way to rollback the forced destruction of rights on PS ?

Comment: What do the permission sets' `Last Modified By` say?

Comment: Updated in december, so it can not be a manual update or a deployment :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not maintaining any backup of these then I am afraid it wont be possible. You can still raise a ticket with salesforce and check it.

Comment: I luckily have metadata backups of this org (that's how I tracked the origin of the update: same day than Spring22 upgrade) , but I work at a Salesforce Integrator company and i'd like to know i t can happen on any of the many many orgs we maintain :/

Comment: I think you should raise a case with Salesforce to find out what really happened, and to let the wider community know what you are told since this seems really worrying to me.